# How can I work on a WordPress theme already installed in the root directory?

Tags: wordpress, htaccess

I have WordPress installed at the root level of a website.
I thought it would be easy enough to have a "coming soon" page called `default.html` and edit the `.htaccess` file as follows:

> ```
> AddHandler php5-script .php
> DirectoryIndex default.html index.php
> # BEGIN WordPress
> # END WordPress
> ```

...so that visitors to the site are sent to the default page, and I could manually specify `index.php` as my destination for testing. (This isn't a high-security job.) But `index.php` is redirecting me to the default page. When I remove the `DirectoryIndex` line, the `index.php` file is found automatically by visitors to the site root, but... that's the page I was trying to hide.

What am I doing wrong with `.htaccess` and how can I get it to behave the way I want?

Comment: You may want to ask this at the [Wordpress StackExchange site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com)

Comment: That site only has like 4 users- questions go days without being answered.. I knew I had a better shot here.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I use a different (easier) method of achieving the same thing.

- create a simple "coming soon" theme (I think there is one in the gallery you can modify).
- install the Theme Test Drive (TTD) plugin here's the info: http://www.prelovac.com/vladimir/wordpress-plugins/theme-test-drive
- Configure TTD to send all standard users to your "coming soon" theme and you (admin user) to the design you're working on automatically
- you can send links to others (non-admin users) for feedback by simply adding a url variable
- when you're happy with the design simply make the new design the default and disable TTD

It's worked really well for me and might be a bit simpler for future/frequent mods than hacking .htaccess.

Good luck,
James